# is there a faster way to disable multiple keys

Tags: javascript

```js
if(event.keyCode === 13 ){
    return false;
  }
```

basically this simple code above disables a specific key, now i wanted to disable a lot of keys so i came up with something like

```js
if(event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 14 || event.keyCode === 15 || event.keyCode === 16 , etc)
```

is there a faster way to do this instead of having to put a lot of `||`s?

im not really sure if this has been asked before but i tried searching and couldnt find anything

Comment: Turn it on its head. Make an array of keys you want to allow and then check if the keycode is in that array.

Comment: [About keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the keyCodes in a array and check against the array with `includes()`

```js
const keyCodes = [13, 14, 15, 16];

if (keyCodes.includes(event.keyCode)) {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of keycode you want to disable:

```
const disabledKeys = [13, 14, 15, 16];

const isKeyDisabled = (keyCode) => disabledKeys.indexOf(event.keyCode) > -1

if(isKeyDisabled(event.keyCode)){
  return false;
}
```